# ConfigParser printing config to string with TOML/ini format

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I'm trying to use ConfigParser to edit a string that stores a .ini file content.
To import the string I use `ConfigParser.read_string(my_string)`.
what I'm looking for is the exact opposite function so I can later set my string's value as content of my confing object.

I could use f-string in some loop but this wouldn't be ideal in my opinion.

```python
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()


sample_config = """
[settings]
user = jeff
help = pls
"""
config.read_string(sample_config)

config["settings"]["user"] = "Orili"


sample_config = config.write_string()
```

**the function `write_string()` does not exist**

what I want:

```
print(sample_config)
```

**output:**

```
[settings]
    user = Orili
    help = pls
```